# Android - How to know that I lost Permission to check calls (on Marshmallow)

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-permissions

I have an app that makes calls to a list of specific numbers.

Here's my Receiver from the Manifest:

```
        <receiver android:name=".manager.sos.CallReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

And with that I know exactly when a call is made and when it finishes.
When one call finishes, I make a new call after my "onOutgoingCallEnded" method beeing called.
The method "onOutgoingCallEnded", is called through my `CallReceiver`, based on TelephonyManager states: `EXTRA_STATE_IDLE`, `EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK`, `EXTRA_STATE_RINGING`... So if CallReceiver isn't called, I don't reach the "onOutgoingCallEnded" method

My problem begin with Android 6.0 (marshmallow), because, even if the user gives permission to CALLS, he can any time he wants, reverse it on the App Settings.

So while the call is being made, and the user denies permission, I don't see my "onOutgoingCallEnded" method being called, because I lost permission to check Calls State.

So How can I know that I lost Permission to check Calls?

Answer (score 1):

> So How can I know that I lost Permission to check Calls?

You don't, at least not immediately. Android will terminate your process when you lose permission. It will not call any methods on your app to tell you that you lost permission.

You will only find out when your code runs for other reasons (e.g., user taps on your launcher icon), where you can call `checkSelfPermission()` to see whether you still have permission or not.

Your scenario is uncommon, but it reflects a bit of a hole in the runtime permission system, IMHO. Ideally, you would find out that your receiver will no longer be receiving such broadcasts.

Comment: Thank you for you answer.
It clear a lot of things for me.
Guess I will have to think of another way

Answer (score 1):

When a call would be initiated it may be possible that the activity's pause method will be called and when the user comes back to the application the activity's resume method will be called so you can check for the permission in onResume and if the user would have withdrawn the permission you would be able to come to know about it

Comment: That's a good ideia, but I was trying to avoid that.
I'll probably store the permission value before the call, and then check it after...

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems you've answered your own question. The simplest way (as I see it) would be for you to check if your `onOutgoingCallEnded()` method is being called to know if you have lost permission to check call state.

Comment: maybe I wasn't clear... the method "onOutgoingCallEnded", is called through my `CallReceiver`... based on TelephonyManager states: `EXTRA_STATE_IDLE`, `EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK`, `EXTRA_STATE_RINGING`... So if CallReceiver isn't called, I don't reach the "onOutgoingCallEnded" method

Any other idea?

Comment: Would this be of help? (https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)[https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html]. The section titled: 'Check For Permissions'

Comment: Thank you again for your comment..
But problem is that I don'tknow that I lost permission...  So How do I know that I need to check permission?

Comment: It seems I'm late to the game. user13 answered that there is no callback when you loose a specific permission. So again, best idea would be to check every time.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the `targetSdkVersion` to 23 or higher, you'll be automatically requested to preface any part of code that uses "dangerous" permissions with a permission check. That way, you will "know" if you have lost your permission, i.e. each time your app needs to perform something that requires a permission that had been denied, it can ask the user to re-enable it, stating the reason for it. You can read about it in more detail here: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: Hi, thank you for you answer, but I don't think you fully understand my question

I already asked the user the permission to check calls... The problem is how to know if he disabled the same permission (on the App Settings)

Any ideas?

Comment: I think you don't understand how the permission system works. As soon as your app needs to perform an action that requires a permission it will check for it. It doesn't matter whether it was disabled through a dialog or through the settings.  Please read the link me and the other poster gave you and you might understand it a bit better.

Comment: As I told on my question, I already asked the user for permission...
The problem is to know when he disabled the permission. Because I'm waiting for a call from the CallReceiver, but it never arrives, because Permission has been revoked on the way... And waiting for `OnResume` to be call, to check again is not an ideal solution
Do you have any idea how to do this?

Comment: I don't know much about your specific use-case, but it strikes me as a bit odd that the user would revoke a permission mid-call (they'd have to look at the screen and navigate the menus until they reach the settings...). Anyway, you might set up another thread which will occasionally check if the permission has been revoked and then ask for it again... Or, when you could set up some kind of semaphore or lock. Then, when the user tries to make a new call and is unable because onOutgoingCallEnded hasn't been called, you could check if the permission is still in place.

Answer (score 0):

With Android 6.0 Marshmallow, Google introduced a new permission model. Rather than the user blindly accepting all permissions at install time, the user is now prompted to accept permissions as they become necessary during application use. To provide a graceful handling of permission removal scenario you should do the following :

- Even if the permission has been previously granted it is necessary to check again to be sure that the user did not later revoke that permission.

Code

```
 private boolean hasPermission(String permission){

        if(checkForMarshMallow()){
            return(checkSelfPermission(permission)==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);

        }

        return true;

    }

    boolean checkForMarshMallow(){

        return(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1);

    }
```

The above method uses the method checkSelfPermission(String perm). This method is present in the Activity class and is used to return an integer value of PERMISSION_GRANTED or PERMISSION_DENIED which you can make use of

Comment: Hi, thank you for you answer... But I don't think you understood my question...
I already asked the user for permission... The problem is knowing that I lost the permission... (without checking on `onResume`)

Got any ideas?